# Same methods, different templates: how to keep methods in one place?

Tags: angular, typescript, architecture

The project right now has different components for desktop and mobile app layout.
But both components use practically the same logic inside. It's simple operations like rename / delete / create.

And if we need to change something, it always doubles workload, because you need to change the logic in both components.

How to make two components use the same methods, but keep different templates?
What is the best practice?

Comment: Inheritance and abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you are having 3 components which will have same functionality.
Lets say , Component 1 = one , Component 2 = two, Component 3 = three.

Step 1 :-
Make a service file name commonService.ts file.
Make a function :-

```
public getData() {
  //do your code here
}
```

Step 2:-
Register commonService.ts file in contructor of  all 3 components as follows:-

```
contructor(public commonService: CommonService){}
```

call `getData()` function in any component you want:-

```
this.commonService.getData();
```

Comment: in typescript, inside a service you should write: `getData(){..}` better than `function getData(){...}`